Offset animation issue in SwiftUI
I'm trying to create a pulsating visualisation animation as can be seen here. Here's what I've come up with so far.
struct ContentView: View {
    private let offsetAnimDuration: Double = 0.2
    private let barCount = 200
    @State private var barOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()

            ForEach(0..<barCount) { i in
                Bar(barMinHeight: 1, barMaxHeight: 50, barWidth: 2, barColor: .white)
                    .offset(y: barOffset)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: offsetAnimDuration), value: barOffset)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(360/Double(barCount)) * Double(i))
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { _ in
                barOffset = -CGFloat.random(in: 100...150)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Bar: View {
    let barMinHeight: CGFloat
    let barMaxHeight: CGFloat
    let barWidth: CGFloat
    let barColor: Color
    private let animDuration: Double = 0.5
    @State private var animHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: barWidth / 2)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(width: barWidth, height: animHeight)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: animDuration), value: animHeight)
                .onAppear {
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animDuration, repeats: true) { _ in
                        animHeight = CGFloat.random(in: barMinHeight...barMaxHeight)
                    }
                }
        }
        .frame(height: barMaxHeight, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}

The issues that I'm seeing are

The pulsating animation isn't smooth as in the link.
Animating the y-offset results in the bars sometimes displaying detached above or below the offset i.e. not anchored (see screenshot)


Also, is it possible to achieve the animation seen here ? It looks similar to the first effect except there are groups of bars animating at a time with some extended shadowy-glow effect which I haven't been able to wrap my head around. Any help is appreciated.

The syntax for static range is ForEach(0..<200) { i in. Timer inside onAppear is prob a bad idea since structs have no lifetime. Try .task and a for loop with a task.sleep.

I have done some tests and even tried using Path instead of a view, but it didn’t help. I think this is the limit of SwiftUI animation; you may need to do this in Metal and represent it as a view.

In your original code, if you set the state to @State private var barOffset: CGFloat = -.random(in: 100...150) and comment out the .onAppear of ContentView, the bars should animate better.

To overcome the offset issues, I would suggest drawing a black circle in the center of the view and then adjusting its size with animation. This way, the offset of the individual bars can remain contstant.
In the original animation, the bars are not solid but have dashed ends. One way to get this effect is to stroke the bars as lines, using a StrokeStyle with dash effect.
This answer by lorem ipsum provides a good overview of ways in which timed events can be triggered. For the animation here, it works well to use task(id:).
Here is an updated version of your example that tries to emulate the first animation:
EDIT Following up on the comments, the CPU load can be reduced by grouping the bars together. Solution updated.
struct ContentView: View {
    private let barMinHeight: CGFloat = 20
    private let barMaxHeight: CGFloat = 80
    private let nGroups = 20
    private let nBarsPerGroup = 10
    private let minCoreSize: CGFloat = 180
    private let maxCoreSize: CGFloat = 200
    private let coreAnimDuration: Double = 0.2
    @State private var coreSize: CGFloat = 50

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()

            ForEach(0..<nGroups, id: \.self) { i in
                BarGroup(
                    barMinHeight: barMinHeight,
                    barMaxHeight: barMaxHeight,
                    barOffset: minCoreSize / 2,
                    barWidth: 2,
                    barColor: .white,
                    nBars: nBarsPerGroup
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(360/Double(nGroups * nBarsPerGroup)) * Double(i))
            }

            Circle()
                .fill(.black)
                .frame(width: coreSize)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: coreAnimDuration), value: coreSize)
                .task(id: coreSize) {
                    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(coreAnimDuration))
                    coreSize = CGFloat.random(in: minCoreSize...maxCoreSize)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct BarGroup: View {
    let barMinHeight: CGFloat
    let barMaxHeight: CGFloat
    let barOffset: CGFloat
    let barWidth: CGFloat
    let barColor: Color
    let nBars: Int
    private let animDuration = Double.random(in: 0.1...0.2)
    @State private var barHeights: [CGFloat]

    struct Line: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
            return path
        }
    }

    init(barMinHeight: CGFloat, barMaxHeight: CGFloat, barOffset: CGFloat, barWidth: CGFloat, barColor: Color, nBars: Int) {
        self.barMinHeight = barMinHeight
        self.barMaxHeight = barMaxHeight
        self.barOffset = barOffset
        self.barWidth = barWidth
        self.barColor = barColor
        self.nBars = nBars
        self.barHeights = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: nBars)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<nBars, id: \.self) { i in
                Line()
                    .stroke(style: .init(
                        lineWidth: barWidth,
                        lineCap: .round,
                        dash: [2, barWidth, 2, barWidth, 3, barWidth, 4, barWidth, 1000]
                    ))
                    .frame(width: barWidth, height: barHeights[i])
                    .frame(maxHeight: barMaxHeight, alignment: .bottom)
                    .frame(width: 2 * barMaxHeight, height: 2 * barMaxHeight, alignment: .top)
                    .offset(y: -barOffset)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(360/Double(nBars)) * Double(i))
            }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(barColor)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: animDuration), value: barHeights)
        .task(id: barHeights) {
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(animDuration))
            var newHeights = [CGFloat]()
            for _ in 0..<nBars {
                newHeights.append(CGFloat.random(in: barMinHeight...barMaxHeight))
            }
            barHeights = newHeights
        }
    }
}


For the second animation, the following differences apply:

There is no pulsing core (the core doesn't change size).
The bars have different colors, but the color at any particular position appears to be fixed.
Each bar consists of a wide line of solid color with a round end, combined with a semi-transparent line which is approximately twice the length.
The semi-transparent overlay lines have an opacity gradient. A dash effect is not used.
The heights of the bars are not random but follow a repeating sine-like curve.
Every peak in the curve has a random maximum height, but the lows in the curve seem to be fairly constant.
The peaks seem to move around the circle, they are not at fixed positions.

If you have difficulties getting the second animation to work then I would suggest it would be best if it was addressed in a separate post.

I appreciate the amount of detail you include along with the solution @BenzyNeez, thank you! I'll post the second animation separately so as to not cloud this one.

I have a followup question, when trying out the solution I see that the CPU usage in Xcode 16's Debug Navigator is consistently between 100-110% when running on an iPhone 16 simulator. Is there a way to lower this? I assume the high usage is because of the number of animations occurring.

@batman Yes, I noticed it was quite high when running as a debug build (about 90% of one CPU in my case). I think this is to be expected, considering how busy the animation is. It is less when running as a release build. Maybe it would be even less, if the bars would be grouped, so that one trigger then updates multiple bars. You probably don't want adjacent bars to be grouped, it would be better if they were distributed. However, I don't think it will help much, because it is probably the animated change that is expensive.

Interesting point about release build performance, I'll try that. I've been tinkering with pre-computing the bar heights as an array in the parent view and passing them into each individual Bar view and I see significant reduction in CPU usage. However the downside is that the animation isn't really random as in the original & trying to randomise the bar heights periodically brings us back to the same problem causing the animation to be erratic.

I'm accepting the answer since it does what I asked for. Thanks @BenzyNeez !

I tried out the idea of grouping the bars and it reduces the CPU load by a lot, answer updated. Ps. Thanks for accepting it!
